# Is it possible to find out last modified date in android studio project?

Tags: android, date, android-studio

I an had exam in `Android` App development in my university. It was a home exam and we had 5 days for our projects. Deadline was last Friday and I delivered the wrong project with almost same name. Now I have to send complaint for exams office and explain that I actually had made project until the deadline.

So I was wondering is it possible to find out last modified date that I could use as a clue or evidence that I have made my project at the right time and that other project I have sent was by mistake.

Comment: You could use 'date modified' on the file system.  Or "stat filename.txt" from command line to get info on a file or directory.

Comment: How do you do that? If I i send it to others will it show the same date? Or will it only show on last modified date on my computer system?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on your **project** in project structure on the left, then

   Local History -> Show History
2. If you want to show history only for **src folder**, click on it then

   Local History -> Show History

... the same for layout folder

3. Or

   **VCS** -> Local History -> Show History

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project src then go to Local History and then Show history